does Email service consider context user's permissions while creating case through custom apex class in the salesforce?
enter image description here  Iam creating case and Task records when email is received to email address using an Apex class as inbound email handler, I got a requirement i.e case and task should be created in the system only when context user is having object level permission to case and task objects.
So i have created separate permission set for context user, i have tested sent an email to email address eventhough context user is not having permission case and task was created.
1.I need to know whether email-to-case consider context user's permission ?
2. Email service runs on context user or system context?
3. Is there a way to restrict creating case and task records when context user is not having access?
Please refer the attachment for more info
